# jquery mobile - Page flickers on loading of long ListView in iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am developing a phone gap application for ios and using Backbone.js jQuerymobile and jQuery to load my list-view.

The page flickers when ever a long listview loads or just becomes visible. This doesnot happen with listviews with smaller length like 6 to 7 elements.

I have already used `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` for `.ui-page`. I am not getting this problem in android

Comment: Show us an example of your code. How and when you you populate a listview?

Comment: I am populating the list-view using Backbone.js on jQuerymobile's 'pageshow' event. It's not just while loading, even if i make the list-view 'visibility:visible' from 'display:none', the screen flickers

Comment: Do it inside a pagebeforeshow event. Your flickering is caused by jQM populating a listview while page is already been shown.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering in my page is caused because of dom reflow.

since i am adding content to the listview dynamically, dom reflow was happening everytime i add an element to the listview which is causing the flickering in my page.

I have changed my dome structure to make sure that the  element comes directly under the  with data-role="content" so that reflow doesn't effect any other elements.